# Java program throwing headless exception from terminal on MacOSX

Tags: java, swing, headless

I have a java program with swing gui and graphics2d and it runs fine from Eclipse but when I export it and run it (on the same machine) I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:202)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:534)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:224)
at com.lunumia.frame.MainFrame.createFrame(MainFrame.java:17)
at com.lunumia.start.Lunumia.main(Lunumia.java:26)
```

And it's a macbook pro.. not a server or anything.

Edit: Line 26:

```
MainFrame.createFrame();
```

in createFrame():

```
frame = new JFrame("Lunumia");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(900, 600);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
panel = new PanelLogin(frame);
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyboardListener());
frame.addMouseListener(new MouseClickListener(panel));
frame.add(panel);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

EDIT: Found out caused by Java 1.7, works on computers without. However, I cannot downgrade, it literally just says that java 1.7 internal is installed when I delete java. How do i get this to work?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - can you successfully run Oracle's Swing examples from the tutorial (via the links to launch the GUI)?

Comment: *"code examples!"*  A code snippet is not an SSCCE.  Those snippets do not tell me which line of code throws the exception.  Prepare an SSCCE and give a new stack trace (with line numbers correct for the SSCCE).  Also, don't forget to answer my questions.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes I can, it works in Eclipse as well, its only when I export is that it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I don't know which line is throwing the error, I can only get the error in terminal.

Comment: Eclipse has it's own JVM. Whatever one you have installed on your Mac is the problem. Try installing the lastest Java (7) from Oracle and getting rid of anything that's on the machine currently.

Comment: I could ask the next 10 questions about the code not included, but I am lazy, so I won't.  Post an SSCCE that contains the answers and I will look further into it.

Comment: I'm not sure what code you want, the error is being called by frame = new JFrame, it thinks that my computer is headless but its not. @BrianRoach I've tried installing java, how do i go about removing all jvms?

Comment: I have no issues.  Your sample code isn't enough, we need a fully running example to test

Comment: Reinstalling did not work.

Comment: @QuinnFinney - run java -version on your computer and include that information in your question.

Comment: Just to be sure: run your code on the Event Dispatch Thread as it involves swing components

Comment: Check your command line environment for anything [*Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html), e.g. something referenced in the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.